# Reading the RouteConfig array

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to read Angular 2's RouteConfig data?  I'd like to build a breadcrumb.  I tried using ng2-breadcrumb package but Reflect.getOwnMetadata is no longer supported.

Comment: No, it's not possible natively. You will have to wait until this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7617) is implemented.

Comment: You could have access to the config within the `RouteConfig` annotations but it could not contain all the routes (specially if they are added dynamically)...